# CS0433 The type 'EventListener' exists in both 'Square.OkHttp3, Version=3.0.0.0, and 'Squareup.OkHttp3.OkHttp, Version=1.0.0.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I'm creating xamarin android binding for aar. In this binding project I'm using third party squreup NgGet Packages for server-client communication. I added *'Kwon.Squareup.Retrofit2.Retrofit-converter'* to make HTTP requests against a REST API and *'Square.OkHttp3.UrlConnection'* for cookie handling. Now I'm getting a build error

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   CS0433 The type 'EventListener' exists in both 'Square.OkHttp3,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and
>   'Squareup.OkHttp3.OkHttp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' DirectionsBinding

In both package reference contains build-in *Square.OkHttp3* dependency.

Here I added code for where the error occurred in binding project.

```
static IntPtr n_EventListener_Lokhttp3_EventListener_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_p0)
{
    global::Com.Nenative.Directions.NENativeDirections.Builder __this = global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Com.Nenative.Directions.NENativeDirections.Builder> (jnienv, native__this, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer);
    global::Square.OkHttp3.EventListener p0 = global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Square.OkHttp3.EventListener> (native_p0, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer);
    IntPtr __ret = JNIEnv.ToLocalJniHandle (__this.EventListener (p0));
    return __ret;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you will have to delete one of the references

Comment: Or rename one of them using XML metadata transforms.. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata#renaming-members